# PC Task performance

Tags: ibm-pc, emulation, amiga-500

What sort of performance I can expect from PC Task 4.4 on Amiga 500 + 030 50MHz MMU, 64MB RAM? Would it be possible to run Windows 3.11 / 95 and have any real use from it?

Comment: Anecdotal information - I just fired up PC Task 1.02 on my 25Mhz A3000 and launched FoxPro 2.0 - which took about 30 seconds to load.  It's sluggish, but not unusable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have an A1200 with Blizzard 1230-IV (50MHz 68030/MMU/FPU) and 32 MiB of FastRAM.  I installed DOS 6.22 and Windows 3.0 into a 20 MB hardfile on a CF card in the PCMCIA slot. I ran it under [PC-Task 4.4](http://aminet.net/package/misc/emu/PC-Task44) Dynamic with 'huge' code buffer, 1 MiB extended memory and VGA graphics emulation on PAL screens (outputting composite video to my LCD TV).

DOS performance was quite good, feeling significantly faster than my [Amstrad PC2086](https://oldcomputer.info/pc/ams2086/index.htm). I ran [Checkit 3.0](https://winworldpc.com/product/checkit/30) to benchmark performance. Here are the results (screens captured with SGrab by [Stephan Rupprecht](https://stephan-rupprecht.de/)):-

- CPU

[image]

Initially Checkit measured the CPU speed at 5.3 MHz, but when running the test again (with the code now running from PC-Task's dynamic cache) it jumped up to 12.48 MHz. FPU speed is impressive...

- Hard drive

[image]

The CF card really shines here, providing about 50% native transfer speed under emulation. In comparison my PC2086 only manages a miserable 29 kB/s,  perhaps because its hard drive sector [interleave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interleaving_(disk_storage)) is not optimal.

- Video

[image]

Running 640x200 in 16 colors with 'immediate' screen update, the performance is about what you would expect from a real machine of the same class. It might be a bit slower on an A500 due to reduced ChipRAM bandwidth - best to use MGA (Hercules) text mode if you don't need color.

However the screen update speed in Windows 3.0 was very slow, whether 'immediate' or updating every 4 frames. I suspect this is due to inefficiencies in the stock Windows VGA driver and other code. Windows operation was slow in general - fast enough to be usable *but* you need to be patient.

Finally the acid test - was it fast enough to enjoy playing Solitaire? The answer is... yes!

[image]

Total memory usage (including screen etc.) on the A1200 was ~13 MiB, which was no problem for my 34 MiB system. I even managed to (accidentally) run two virtual PCs at the same time!

But what about Windows 95? In mid 1995 I installed a pre-release version on my 386-DX 40MHz with 4 MiB RAM and ISA bus VGA, and it was sluggish. So while it should run under PC-Task I imagine it would be much too slow for practical use.